# netdata > influxdb > icinga2

Tags: influxdb, icinga2, netdata

I have netdata monitoring installed on all servers. I use InfluxDB for backend and I also have Icinga2.  Is it possible to push some metrics to IcingaWeb2 for alerts and configure alerts for thresholds from InfluxDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can push data from InfluxDB and Icinga2 to [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) then configure [alerts](http://docs.grafana.org/alerting/rules/) from there.